# generic function that can return T? or T depending on whether T is struct or class

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create a generic function but I want it to return T? for value types byte T for reference types. The easy way is to create 2 functions:

```
public T GetRef<T> where T : class

public T? GetStruct<T> where T : struct
```

But is there any way to do it so that I can just have one method (or one method name). I tried:

```
public T Get<T> where T : class

public T? Get<T> where T : struct
```

but this is not allowed (the `where` clause is not part of the function signature). I cant imagine how to put the code in one function.

Comment: You can't.  Plain and simple as that.

Comment: Does `Get` take any parameters?  How are you planning to call it?

Comment: ok - so the duplicate shows how it can be done :-) I suggest that the 'cant be done ' answerers look there too. TY Cody

Comment: @pm100 If you show what your input parameter types are you might be able to do it, but you don;t show any, so I'm assuming there is no input parameter.

Comment: There are many shenanigans you can do in C# if you pass in extra parameters, for instance you can easily create a method that casts an `object` to an anonymous type, provided you know which type to expect and can provide an example of it: `public T CastByExample<T>(object input, T example) => (T)input;` Now you can do: `var x = CastByExample(something, new { a = 0, b = 0 });` will cast `something` into the anonymous type provided as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Neither the return type nor generic constraints are part of the method signature for binding purposes, so there is no way to disambiguate those methods at compile-time.

You *could* use dummy input parameters like the marked duplicate answer does to disambiguate them:

```
public T Get<T>(RequireClass<T> ignore = null) where T : class 

public T? Get<T>(RequireStruct<T> ignore = null) where T : struct

public class RequireStruct<T> where T : struct { }
public class RequireClass<T> where T : class { }
```

Comment: and there is no way to write this as one function?

Comment: Not as cleanly as you like.  You can always use the first signature (withing the `class` constraint) and have `T` be a nullable type but I get the feeling that's not what you want.

Comment: actually it can be done - look at the dup question

Comment: @pm100 That example uses different _input types_ not different _return types_.

Comment: yes but it can be massaged to do exactl what I want - the extra input args are decalred with defaults and so can be left out by the caller)